# C#: efficient way to check if datetime.Day within a certain range?

Tags: c#

Given a `DateTime`, I want to check if the `.Day` is between a number, say between 15 and 19.

So `9/16/2013` passes, but `9/20/2013` fails.

Thanks,

Comment: Why i cannot add answers ?

Comment: @meorfi: Don't worry. Seems this question got more than enough answers :D

Comment: @huMpty duMpty, there was no answer at the moment when I noticed the problem...

Answer (score 11):

Including

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
if (date.Day >= 15 && date.Day <= 19)
{
        return true;
}
```

Excluding

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
if (date.Day > 15 && date.Day < 19)
{
        return true;
}
```

I´m not 100% sure which one is right ;)

Comment: This won't work if now is 30 september for instance;

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: Isn't that the desired behavior?

Comment: shouldn't it be `<= 19`

Comment: can you please explain me why? don´t see it ^_^

Comment: @sine, I am not sure as well, but its an easy fix for the OP. +1 though :)

Comment: @Habib I'm saying that the `date.Day` checking does not take account of the month.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: The OP mentioned no requirement about month checking...

Comment: @RobvanderVeer, from the question it appears that is the desired behaviour

Comment: i removed the <= >= I think between is exclusive but I´m also not sure about this just found this
http://www.urch.com/forums/gmat-math/126565-does-between-x-y-include-x-y.html

Comment: @sine: This depends on semantics commonly used for the context under discussion.  I would disagree with the posted link's conclusion in this case.

Comment: I´ve updated the answer with both possibilities! But I think you´re right it should be including the days

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
return (date.Day >= 15 && date.Day <= 19);
```

Since this is just a range, you can use less than or greater than operators for comparison. Also, you might use the >= or <= operators for including the start or end day.

An alternative approach based on the fact that only one predicate must be true for the date to be out of the range:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
return !(date.Day < 15 || date.Day > 19)
```

Comment: +1 The second approach is the most efficient.

Comment: Thanks! I based my second approach on your comments.

Comment: There is no need to have `if(...)return true; else return false;`.  Whenever you see that you can just replace it with `return ...;`  In this case, sense it's reversed, it's just `return !...;`

Answer (score 2):

```
if((DateTime.Today.Day >= 15) && (DateTime.Today.Day <= 19))
{
    //do something
}
else
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** (because of the error which you can see in the picture (in comments) i wasn't able to post the answer.)

```
private bool IsInRange(DateTime yourDate, DateTime lowestRange, DateTime highestRange) {
   return yourDate.Day >= lowestRange.Day && yourDate.Day <= highestRange.Day; 
}
```

Comment: Why check both if one is already false? Quite an overcomplication.

Comment: sorry, i cannot submit the full answer because the stackoverflow site block my method which contains the word `return` :(

Comment: Why not just `return yourDate.Day < lowestRange.Day || yourDate.Day > highestRange.Day`? I don't know why you're using the bitwise & operator. You should use the boolean || operator as Rotem points out that only one must be true.

Comment: yes, my original method is what you pasted, but i don't know why stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post it... i'll show the snippet with the error

Comment: ![stackoverflow validates as error in code][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KF6dn.jpg

Comment: Ah, the dreaded can't post answer error. I'm not exactly sure why this happens, but I feel your pain. Also, you're almost correct. If you're going to use the boolean `||` operator, you need to change it to my original comment.

Comment: cannot post `&&` toghether :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Day` property directly to check if your date is within some range using code from  other answers.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) says that

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the DateTime structure contains a 64-bit field composed of a private Kind field concatenated with the Ticks field.

Therefore, the most efficient way to compare `DateTime` instances is to use `Ticks` property:

```
DateTime dateToValidate = SomeDate();
DateTime start = SomeRangeStart();
DateTime end = SomeRangeEnd();

return start.Ticks <= dateToValidate.Ticks && dateToValidate.Ticks <= end.Ticks;
```

Answer (score -1):

To properly test if a date (day) is between given numbers, you must use the entire date, or the formula will fail if the date reaches the end of the month.

The example below checks the margin by adding days (or subtracticting days) by using `AddDate` to greate the boundary date. Then check if the current date is between the boundaries.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
if(date.AddDays(-5) < now && now < date.AddDays(5))
{
   return true;
}
```

Comment: -1 What does this have to do with anything?

Comment: @Rotern. All you people are quick to downvote, I am trying to explain that just checking the `.Day` is not sufficient, if the date you are trying to test is close to a months start or end. Therefore you must test if the entire date is between to dates.

Comment: That really wasn't the question. Nowhere does it say anything about `Now`.

Comment: @Rotem the original question is about a date? Otherwise why would OP mention two dates? Anyway, my guess is that OP will eventually find out.

Comment: The question is about determining if a date falls between two other dates. Not if a date is +-5 days from now.

Comment: I give up. If people don't appreciate me here, i'm off.

Comment: I downvoted an answer I thought was wrong. I gave feedback on that downvote because that is a site guideline. You shouldn't be taking it personally.

Comment: +1, For the idea, I guess the OP would have considered month as well, but since its not specified in the question, its upto OP to clarify.